# solidity_flattener fails: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Tags: solidity

Looking to flatten a Solidity project into a single file.

```
user@eth:/code/myproject$ touch contracts/CtdToken.sol
user@eth:/code/myproject$ truffle compile
Compiling ./contracts/CtdToken.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/InterfaceUpgradeAgent.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/MintableToken.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/UpgradableToken.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Withdrawable.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/lifecycle/Pausable.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/BasicToken.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20Basic.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

user@eth:/code/myproject$ solidity_flattener --solc-paths=zeppelin-solidity=/code/myproject/node_modules/zeppelin-solidity ./contracts/CtdToken.sol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/solidity_flattener", line 4, in <module>
    flattener.core.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flattener/core.py", line 96, in main
    solc_proc = subprocess.run(solc_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
user@eth:/code/myproject$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), `subprocess.run` was added in Python 3.5. From the path in the error message, it looks like you're trying to run this script with Python 2.7, but it seems to require Python 3.x.

Comment: user@eth:/code/myproject$ sudo -H python3 -m pip install solidity-flattener